# Lucene SearcherManager maybeRefresh writes to index files?

Tags: java, lucene

I am using Lucene 8.5 and this is what I am doing right now in my application:

1. Do some index operations using `IndexWriter`.
2. Call `SearcherManager.maybeRefreshBlocking()`  ( `SearcherManager` created with the same `IndexWriter`).
3. then tar the directory containing the indexes files on the file system.

Then I would get an error like this:

```
tar: ./indexes/_i_Lucene85FieldsIndex-doc_ids_10.tmp: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors.
```

So that tells me the refresh call hasn't finished by the time the tar operation begins.  I need some clarification and help:

1. `maybeRefresh()`/`maybeRefreshBlocking()` is an asynchronous call, and calling it will modify the index files right?
2. Dumb question but what makes this call different than `IndexWriter.commit()` aside from `commit` being a synchronous call?
3. What can I do to ensure the indexes are completely done "refreshing"?  In other words, the index segment files and etc. are no longer being updated.

I did try to add `ReferenceManager.RefreshListener` (https://lucene.apache.org/core/8_5_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/ReferenceManager.RefreshListener.html) to the `SearcherManager` instance and overriding `afterRefresh(boolean)` , but it seems it gets called right after the attempt and not actually when it finishes since I'm still running into the issue above.

```
      searcherManager.addListener(new ReferenceManager.RefreshListener() {
         @Override
         public void beforeRefresh() {
            refreshing = true;
         }

         @Override
         public void afterRefresh(boolean didRefresh) {
            
            if (didRefresh) {
               refreshing = false;
            }
         }
       });
```

Any help and suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

> MaybeRefresh()/maybeRefreshBlocking() is an asynchronous call, and calling it will modify the index files right?

No.  These two methods refresh the reader associated with the `SearcherManager` if any committed or uncommitted writes have occured since the current reader used by the `SearcherManager` was opened.  These methods do not write index changes to disk.
**Update:** When I said "These methods do now write index changes to disk" I wasn't quite right.
It's true they don't commit any changes, but it turns out they do flush the index to disk which creates a new uncommited segment.

> Dumb question but what makes this call different than IndexWriter.commit() aside from commit being a synchronous call?

Not a dumb question.  commit() will actually write to disk any uncommited write operations.  Write to an index are initially uncommitted and buffered in memory until a commit() is called.  When commit() is called those index changes are written to a new index segment.

> What can I do to ensure the indexes are completely done "refreshing"? In other words, the index segment files and etc. are no longer being updated.

Call 'IndexWriter.commit()'